# AFNetworking upload a large number files

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

Let's assume I have an array that contains like 50 files(file path) different sizes including videos and just iterate an array through loop. every iteration creates a new task. will it work or I should do it in queues limiting the number simultaneous upload tasks?

**PS.**
I apologize if this question is a duplicate. I Just was unable to find an answer which solves my specific problem.

Thank you!

Comment: either option is viable, depends what works best for you

Comment: @Fonix Thank you for taking your time to leave a comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using Queues as described in the question. 
Closing question as self-answered.